# Can I use script Tag in Ionic Angular Framework?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Login.page.html

```html
<ion-content class="background">
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  

  <ion-toolbar class="toolbar" > 
 <ion-title class="title">

  Parent's Login Portal


 </ion-title>
<ion-buttons slot="start">  <ion-back-button defaultHref="#"></ion-back-button> </ion-buttons>
 
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<div class="spacing-above-parent-logo"></div>
<div class="container">
<img  src="assets/images/parents.png" class="img">
<h1>Login</h1>
<div class="spacing-below-parent-logo"></div>

</div>
<div class="hero">
<div class="form-box">
<div class="button-box">
  <div id="btn"></div>
  <button type="button" class="toggle-button" onclick="login()">Log In</button>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-button" onclick="register()">Register</button>

    <form id="login" class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" required>
       <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>

 <input type="checkbox" class="check-box">
       <span>Remember Password</span>
 
       <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Log in</button>
    </form>

      <form id="register" class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" required>
       <input type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
       <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>

 <input type="checkbox" class="check-box">
       <span>I agree to the terms and polices</span>
 
       <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Register</button>
    </form>

</div>

</div>

</div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("login");
var y=document.getElementById("register");
var z=document.getElementById("btn");

function register(){

  x.style.left="-400px";
  y.style.left="50px";
  z.style.left="110px";
}

</script>


</ion-content>
```

Login.page.scss

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

ion-toolbar{
  --border-color: red!important; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px red;
}

.title{

    text-align: center;

}

.img{
    width:400px;
    align-content: center;
    border-style:solid;
    padding:1px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:8px solid transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(60deg,#EFA51A,#ce00); 
}

.spacing-above-parent-logo{
height: 40px;

}

h1{

    padding-left: 160px; 
    padding-top:30px;
}

.hero{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.button-box{
    padding-left: 0%;
    width: 350px;
    margin:35px auto;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 9px #ff61241f;
    border-radius:30 px;
     
}
.toggle-button{
padding: 20px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
background:transparent;
border: 0;
position: relative;

}
.check-box{

margin: 30px 10px 30px 0;

}

span{
    color:#777;
    font-size:12px;
  bottom: 63px;
  position:absolute;
  
 

}
.rem-text{
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#btn{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    height: 44%;
    background:linear-gradient(to right,#ff105f,#ffad06);
    transition:0.5s;
}

.input-group{
    top:180px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 280px;
    transition:.5s,
}

.input-field{
    width:100%;
    padding:10x 0;
    margin:5px 0;
    border-top:0;
    border-right:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(240, 22, 22);
    outline:none;
    background:transparent; 
}

.submit-btn{
    width: 85%;
    padding:10px 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    background:linear-gradient(to right,#ff105f,#ffad06);
    border:none;
    border-radius:30px;
}

#login{
    left:50px;
}

#register{
    left:450px;
}
```

The error in the console shows when i click the register button :

> Uncaught TypeError: register is not a function
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login:1)
> onclick @ login:1

Alternatively,I tried designing the same function TS file of the angular. However, it still cannot find the register function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with `<script>` tag in Angular, it's tedious to implement and everything can be easily done the way Angular is set up to do - inside .ts files.

Change `onclick` to `(click)`:

```
<button type="button" class="toggle-button" (click)="register()">Register</button>
```

and put your register() function in login.page.ts:

```
register(){
    var x=document.getElementById("login");
    var y=document.getElementById("register");
    var z=document.getElementById("btn"); 
    x.style.left="-400px";
    y.style.left="50px";
    z.style.left="110px";
 }
```